# Force shell script to keep command in foreground after process substitution

Tags: bash, shell, process-substitution

I have a script that needs to run a jar and redirect its output to another executable, and I need to run this with a few different parameters. I need to run it each time in isolation because it's running some tests on execution time and I don't want them to be influenced by other stuff running. My problem is that once the first command has finished producing its output, the second command should keep on going (for quite a long time), but control returns to the shell and that command continues in background.

The script does something like:

```
java path.to.script param1 >(path/to/other/script param2 param3)
java path.to.script param4 >(path/to/other/script param5 param6)
```

but as soon as the java command in the first line has completed it goes straight to the next line, resulting in the `path/to/other/script` being executed twice at the same time.

To be more clear, I want the prompt to appear only after the whole first command line has finished, that is after `path/to/other/script` has finished its job.

How do I do that?

Comment: `> path/to/Cscript` overwrites the `Cscript` file with the output of `java path.to.java.class param1 param2 param3` command. Do you mean to `java path.to.java.class param1 param2 | path/to/Cscript param3` ?

Comment: ‘*as soon as the java command in the first line has completed it goes straight to the next line*’ Yeah, that’s how it works, and as far as I can tell what you want. What’s the problem with that? And could you clarify whether you’re redirecting the output to a file (as in the example, except it won’t work with the space in the filename), or piping to another command?

Comment: If I used the `|` I would have to wait for the first command to finish, and the second would process its output values. I want the second to work with the stream of output data, hence the `>`. @Biffen `param3` is a parameter, `Cscript` is the name of the executable

Comment: And `>` __overwrites__ the Cscript with the output on stdout of java command. The `Cscript` is never executed. And no, the `|` does not wait for the first command to finish.

Comment: @gioaudino There’s some major misunderstanding. `>` will *overwrite* `path/to/Cscript`, not *execute* it. Well, it would but Bash is probably telling you something about an ambiguous redirect.

Comment: @KamilCuk, mistyped the command line. Just edited the question

Comment: @gioaudino It’s unclear, to me, at least, what you’re trying to achieve. Do you want the output of `java` to be the input of the script? Then `java … | script param param` is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) will indeed continue to run in the background, outside of the calling shell's control.  You probably simply want

```
java path.to.script param1 | path/to/other/script param2 param3
java path.to.script param4 | path/to/other/script param5 param6
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I don't, I do need the java executable to run with process substitution. Is there any possible way I can achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Why do you think you need the process substitution? Clearly you don't if it doesn't behave the way you want. Java doesn't particularly care where its output goes, though you might need to put something like `-` or `/dev/stdout` if your Java program (annoyingly, stupidly) requires an explicit output "file name". You might instead want to refactor it so it writes to stdout if it doesn't receive one

Comment: java doesn't but that script does indeed, and explicitly specifying `stdout` as an output "filename" did the trick! Thank you